# swift - (n C k) and (n P k) - calculating binomial coefficient?

Tags: swift, combinatorics

## **note**: stack overflow incorrectly marked this as duplicate after an answer (there is no built in) was already selected...linked question unrelated

---

What is the simplest built-in way to calculate num. combinations/permutations in Swift? Official Apple library?

**(n C k)**

[image: $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$$]

python3.8:
`math.comb(n,k)`

**(n P k)**

[image: $$P(n,k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$]

python3.8:
`math.perm(n,k)`

Comment: In practical (not mathematical) usage, this is helpful: https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms

Comment: those would be useful for finding the actual permutations/combinations, but i just want something to compute binomial coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift does not provide built-in functions for permutation, combination, or even factorial. But these simple formulas are easy to implement.

Here is a trivial factorial function:

```swift
func factorial(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    return (1...n).reduce(1, { $0 * $1 })
}
```

But note that this will crash where n >= 21 since 21! is too large to fit in an Int variable.

Here is a naive implementation of "perm":

```swift
func perm(n: Int, k: Int) -> Int {
    return factorial(n) / factorial(n - k)
}
```

And for "comb" you can do:

```swift
func comb(n: Int, k: Int) -> Int {
    return perm(n: n, k: k) / factorial(k)
}
```

However, there is a simple improvement to be made for "perm". Let's say n = 5 and k = 2. You can write the formula for perm as:

```
n!     = 5!     = 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5
------   ------   --   -----------------  = 4 * 5
(n-k)! = (5-2)! = 3! = 1 * 2 * 3
```

This boils down to "perm" being equal to (n-k+1) * (n-k+2) * ... n

So let's rewrite the functions to be more efficient:

```swift
func mult(_ range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    return range.reduce(1, { $0 * $1 })
}

func perm(n: Int, k: Int) -> Int {
    return mult((n - k + 1)...n)
}

func comb(n : Int, k: Int) -> Int {
    return perm(n: n, k: k) / mult(1...k)
}
```

Note that the "comb" function didn't actually change other than to use `mult(1...k)` instead of `factorial(k)` which both give the same result.

These functions still have limits on the sizes of n and k before they will crash due to the limits on the `Int` data type.

Comment: I found this [`BigInt`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/test/Prototypes/BigInt.swift) prototype in the swift repo which lets bigger values of n